# Is implementing content owner only access via security rules in firestore safe?

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I saw the below snippet in firebase security rules docs. But is it secure? Like suppose someone alters the `auth.uid` to a `uid` of another person. doesn't that mean he has the write privilege. or is the `auth.id` derived from bearer token at firebase end.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is implementing content owner only access via security rules in
> firestore safe?

Yes it is secure: Firebase ID tokens are created by the Auth service when a user signs in to an app. These tokens are **signed [JWTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)** that securely identify a user in a Firebase project. If a malicious user tries to modify a JWT, the verification of the token by the Firebase backend when evaluating the security rule will fail and the access will be denied.

More info in the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: first of all thanks for the quick reply. So the below given auth payload is only visible to the admin right? and users just see the raw token.
`{
  "uid": "",
  "token": {
    "sub": "",
    "aud": "",
    "email": "",
    "email_verified": false,
    "phone_number": "",
    "name": "",
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question in your comment. The token is visible to the user (it's stored in a cookie if I'm not mistaking) but if it is modified, the backend will detect it when verifying its integrity and the Security Rule will fail.